# Disable focussable items in AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android

I'm creating a **Dialog** with a simple List of items. I want to to **disable the focussable event**.

I'm trying to achieve this with the method `.setOnItemSelectedListener(null)` but it doesn't fix it.

PD: don't want to create a custom DialogFragment just for this simple list.

```
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setAdapter(new AlterationTypesAdapter(getActivity()), null)
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setOnItemSelectedListener(null)
                    .show();
```

Comment: why do you want to disable focusable?

Comment: Because when you tap one item from the list, its background changes to "blue" (default Android behaviour).

Comment: Have you set listview inside dialog ?

Answer (score 2):

You can choose which items in your ListView are selectable in your adapter, overriding the isEnabled method. If you don't want any item to be selectable, just something like this would suffice.

```
public class AlterationTypesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return false;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out by setting `android:listSelector="@null"`